# Android build is failing when updates to compileSDKVersion and targetSDKVersion

Tags: android, react-native, bitrise, intercom

I have faced a problem in making an android build was working perfectly since the last 5 months but my Bitrise workflow is failing when I update compileSDKVersion and targetSDKVersion can you please help me are how to solve this issue

Previous

- compileSdkVersion : 30
- targetSdkVersion : 30

Work perfectly

Currently

- compileSdkVersion : 31
- targetSdkVersion : 31

Can’t work perfectly

Screen-short
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/80ewD.png

Note:- My project is built in React Native framework, On my local system this project works perfectly and successfully created android build

System Specification:-
OS:- Monterey
RAM:- 16 GB
JDK Version:- 11.0.15
React native version:- 0.65.1

Answer (score 0):

Updating just the SDK versions like that will cause problems because other pieces of React Native might be tied to it. You have to upgrade React Native to the latest version (or whichever version that supports SDK 31).

Undo your changes and upgrade using React Native CLI's `upgrade` command.

```
npx react-native upgrade
```

You can read more about it [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/upgrading).